# Android MultiDex - A/libc(28851): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), thread 29117 (pool-16-thread-)

Tags: android, segmentation-fault, android-multidex

I am getting this error in my app but only on some devices. So far only a few crashes have been reported. I recently enabled multiDex support and since then it crashes on some of the pre-lollipop devices.

```
A/libc(28851): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), thread 29117 (pool-16-thread-)
```

There is no other information given in the logcat. I saw some other posts on SO but they are different and don't apply to my case. I guess it has to do with memory usage ?

Comment: please post full logcat

Comment: That the only thing i get in the logcat after crash and nothing else.

Comment: It's not possible logcat only have this line. Source of error is before or after this line

Comment: believe me there is nothing else. Logcat offcourse has lots of other information but thats normal stuff and mostly redundant. After the crash this is only line i get.   and as i said it only happens on some devices.

Comment: has any one got the solution ?